# Angular Tab Pagination

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, redux-toolkit, ngrx-store

I'm using angular version `"@angular/cli": "~11.1.1"` with NgRX Store module.The project have all NgRX layers.

**Problem**: I have a screen with a tab with two tabs's contents. In each tabs, there is a `*ngFor="let item of itemListFiltter1$ | async" class="center-text"`. However the pagination is the itemList without filtter. How I control the pagination to change when we change the tabs?

**Code - Selectors:**

```
export const selectItemListFiltter1= createSelector(
  selectItemState,
  ({resultPage}) => resultPage?.result?.filter(val => val.item.codItem == 0)
)
```

**Code - List Component:**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.store.dispatch(startLoad());
    this.itemListFiltter1$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectItemListFiltter1));
    this.itemListFiltter2$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectItemListFiltter2));
  }
```

**UPDATED**

The backend sends the `pagination`. After created the inicial state, we need to change the values like the result by `selectItemListFiltter1` method. Below is the result's json to represent the data:

**Inicial state - backend Json:**

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "totalRows": 6,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "page": 0,
        "pageSize": 10
    },
    "result": [
            {
            "idProduct": 3,
            "item": 1,
            "value": 0.00
        },
        {
            "idProduct": 2,
            "item": 1,
            "value": 0.00
        },
        {
            "idProduct": 10,
            "item": 1,
            "value": 0.00
        },  
        {
            "idProduct": 3,
            "item": 2,
            "value": 0.00
        },
        {
            "idProduct": 2,
            "item": 2,
            "value": 0.00
        },
        {
            "idProduct": 10,
            "item": 2,
            "value": 0.00
        },  
    ],
    "mesages": []
}
```

**After selectItemListFiltter1  expected in the ItemListFiltter1**

P.S. Here is only the representation.

```
  {
        "pagination": {
            "totalRows": 3,
            "totalPages": 1,
            "page": 0,
            "pageSize": 10
        },
        "result": [
            {
                "idProduct": 3,
                "item": 1,
                "value": 0.00
            },
            {
                "idProduct": 2,
                "item": 1,
                "value": 0.00
            },
            {
                "idProduct": 10,
                "item": 1,
                "value": 0.00
            },  
        ],
        "mesages": []
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you please provide the initial state (or the one you are trying to filter on) + current emitted value vs. expected emitted value? When recreating your problem it seems like your selectors are working fine. One hint: You can use `this.store.select(selectItemListFiltter1)` directly instead of using `pipe(select(...`.

Comment: Can I send you two Json?

Comment: Please past it into the description of your question. I assume the initial item state (from a structural perspective) looks something like this:

{
      resultPage: {
        result: [
          { item: { codItem: 1 } },
          { item: { codItem: 2 } },
          { item: { codItem: 0 } },
        ],
      },
    };

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand how the data should match your filter. 1: you are destructuring the state using an attribute name 'resultPage', which is not present in the initial state. 2: you are filtering based on attribute "val.item.codItem", which is also not present in the initial data. How does this match together?

Comment: The filter is OK! The problem is the pagination. When I change the tab, the pagination doesn't change. The backend send this pagination's info when the component list is created. I need to change the pagination dinamicamentily. Answers 1: No, I don’t. 2: Yes, you can think like this ("val.item.codItem"). The codItem is correct. The problem is when I change the codItem. Supose the tab1 has 2 pages and the tab2 6. The pagination still 8 (all list’s elements).

Comment: But you haven‘t even included Code to set the pagination object. I‘m sorry, but your question is still not clear to me. All Code provided is targeting the filter selector.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I cannot share the code. The problem is the pagination change with the amount of the each tab. Now is fixed.

Comment: this paginator component is written by you or is it third party? It seems you are applying filter after receiving data. So let's assume that server send total item count as 100 but after filtering only 10 items remain, what do you want paginator to show as total count?

Comment: Yes, the pagination component is written by us. I need the pagination shows 10 instead of 100.